# Angular one time binding in directive with isolated scope not updating when scope changes

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular 1.3's one time binding in a directive template. The directive has an isolated scope and renders different data according to the selected object. My issue is that when I change the selected object, the one time binded propery doesn't update.

I guess this might be the expected behavior. My question is, can I somehow make the directive template update also the one time binded properties, but not have them be watched?

I attached a plunkr demonstrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NAHVfhCf6RhpJHPGl7El?p=preview

Code:
Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.objects = [
    { name: 'Object1', type: 'Type1' },
    { name: 'Object2', type: 'Type2' }
  ];

  $scope.selectedObject = $scope.objects[0] ;

  $scope.setSelected = function () {
    if($scope.selectedObject == $scope.objects[0]) {
      $scope.selectedObject = $scope.objects[1];
    } else {
      $scope.selectedObject = $scope.objects[0];
    }
  }
});


app.directive('sidebar',function() {
  return {
        scope: { 
            'selected': '=selected',
        }, 
        restrict: 'A', 
        template: 'Name: {{selected.name}}</span><br>Type: <span>{{::selected.type}}</span>',
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="setSelected()">Change selected</button>

    <div sidebar selected="selectedObject"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: you missing the point of one time binding. you must have a watcher if you want the view to update.

Comment: I see, Do you want to write this as an answer? Thanks